# Metal shader texture read vs sample

Tags: ios, shader, metal, metalkit

In Metal shading language, what is the exact difference between read and sample function to access texture pixels, and which one should be used when?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A few differences:

- You can sample outside the bounds of the texture. But you should not read outside the texture.
- Sampling can use normalized coordinates (between 0 and 1). Reading always uses pixel coordinates.
- Samplers can interpolate between pixel values (for example if you're sampling in between two pixels). Reading always gives you the exact pixel value.